# How to remove bottom margin from Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, android-menu

How do I make my Activity fit the entire screen? There is this black bar at the bottom of the screen, and a menu bar on the top of the screen with the apps name. I'd like to have it be just the content inside of the activity.

Is this just a theming issue?

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.DrinkTracker" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

    </style>
</resources>
```

[image: Activity with a top menu bar and bottom margin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a Guide that describes this topic: [Display content edge-to-edge in your app](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge)

And if you want to remove the Toolbar just change the Theme from

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar
```

to

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
```